# Image in container doesn't want to show in my screen Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

The image doesn't show on my screen. Also can someone tell me what's the deal with the flatbutton, the rectangle doesn't show up either.

This is what it should look like: [image: Whatitshouldbelike]

This is my screen [image: Myscreen]

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(

    MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
            body: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                  new Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                      image: new AssetImage("Image/Animegirl.jpg"),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                     Text(
                  "Alice Payne",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white),
                 ),
                         Text(
                  "MOBILE DEVELOPER",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.white),
                 ),
                        FlatButton.icon(
                          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                            color: Colors.white,
                               label: Text("+212612174968",
                                 style:TextStyle(
                                 color: Colors.grey,
                                   ),
                 ),
                                 icon: Icon(Icons.phone,
                                   size: 25,
                                   color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                               onPressed: (null)
                  ),
                         FlatButton.icon(
                             shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            label: Text("hda.karima@gmail.com",
                               style:TextStyle(
                              color:Colors.grey,
                            ),
            ),
                                 icon: Icon(Icons.email,
                                   size: 25,
                                   color: Colors.white,
            ),
                            onPressed: (null)
        ),
        ]),
  ),),


  ),

  );
}
```

Comment: Did you add "Image/Animegirl.jpg" in your pubspec.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

also include `assets`

```
 image: AssetImage("assets/Image/Animegirl.jpg"),
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `onPressed: (null)` with

```
onPressed: () {

    }
```

The style you seeing is of a disabled button as you are not providing onTap method.

Also add asset folder in pubsub.yaml as per your folder structure (If Image folder is inside a assets folder) do it as per your folder structure.

```
  assets:
    - assets/Image/
    - assets/
```

then use `image: new AssetImage("assets/Image/Animegirl.jpg")`

Your code should be something like

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(

    MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
            body: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                  new Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                      image: new AssetImage("Image/Animegirl.jpg"),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                     Text(
                  "Alice Payne",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white),
                 ),
                         Text(
                  "MOBILE DEVELOPER",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.white),
                 ),
                        FlatButton.icon(
                          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                            color: Colors.white,
                               label: Text("+212612174968",
                                 style:TextStyle(
                                 color: Colors.grey,
                                   ),
                 ),
                                 icon: Icon(Icons.phone,
                                   size: 25,
                                   color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                               onPressed: () {

                               }
                  ),
                         FlatButton.icon(
                             shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            label: Text("hda.karima@gmail.com",
                               style:TextStyle(
                              color:Colors.grey,
                            ),
            ),
                                 icon: Icon(Icons.email,
                                   size: 25,
                                   color: Colors.white,
            ),
                            onPressed: () {

                               }
        ),
        ]),
  ),),


  ),

  );
}
```